# Alert box is not showing inside codeigniter controller

Tags: codeigniter

In this controller alert box is not working inside if loop.if condition is working,only problem with the alert box,but its not showing the dialog box.Please help. i tried so many times.

Controller Erp_c

```
function tabl()
{
   $result['query2']=$this->erp_m->getregion();

   $this->load->view('head1');    
        $this->load->view('header3');
   $this->load->view('userregionview',$result);
}    

function userregioninsert($user)
        {

            if($this->input->post())
            $m1=$this->input->post('reg');
        //    print_r($m1);die;

              $result['query']=$this->erp_m->insertregion($m1,$user);
              $result['query2']=$this->erp_m->getregion();
        //      print_r($result['query']);die;
                  if(($result['query'])>0)
                  {

          ?>
                     <script type=text/javascript>alert("Region already added");</script>

        <?php

        }
        else
        {

           ?>
                     <script type=text/javascript>
            alert("Name Available");
        </script>

        <?php

                  $this->erp_m->insertregion2($m1,$user);

                  }

                  redirect('Erp_c/tabl');

                }
```

model
    `erp_m`

```
  function getregion()
      {

            $query2=$this->db->get('region3');
           return $query2->result();
      }
       function insertregion($m1,$user)
      {
           $this->db->where('region',$m1);
           $res=$this->db->get('region3');

            $num=$res->num_rows();        
          return $num;             
      }


 function insertregion2($m1,$user)
        {
            $data=array('region'=>$m1,'user'=>$user);
            $this->db->insert('region3',$data);

        }
```

Comment: Why are you loading script tags on controller function, I think they should on for view.

Comment: don't load any script in controller. Always use it in view. In your case you can save these script to one variable called 'Js' and pass to view for dispalying
$data['js'] = '<script>alert('hello')</script>';

Comment: how to we display it in view page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing with `""`.

This `<script type=text/javascript>` Should come as like this `<script type="text/javascript">`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Region already added");
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Name Available");
</script>
```

**And** Check empty with `empty()` function

**Edit 01**

```
    function insertregion($m1)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE region='$m1' ");//change table name
        $result = $query->result_array();
        $count = count($result);
        return $count;
    }
```

**And** instead of using this `if ( $this->input->post() )` use `if(isset($_POST['reg']))`

So your Final Answer would be

```
    function userregioninsert($user)
    {

        if(isset($_POST['reg']))
        {
            $m1 = $this->input->post('reg');

            $count = $this->erp_m->insertregion($m1);
            $result['query2'] = $this->erp_m->getregion();

            if ($count==1)
            {
                ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("Region already added");
                </script>
            <?php
            }
            else
            {
                ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("Name Available");
                </script>
                <?php
                $this->erp_m->insertregion2($m1, $user);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('Erp_c/tabl');
        }           

    }
```

Comment: No sir ,still alert box is not getting

Comment: so problem is with `$result['query'] = $this->erp_m->insertregion($m1, $user);`

Comment: yes i am getting the alertbox.but when i click ok button in the alertbox,it will go to the function'userregioninsert' and i am seeing a blank page

Comment: when i click ok in alert box i want to go to the function' tabl'.thank you so much for your support

Comment: after then use `$this->function_name();`

Answer (score 2):

e.g.

```
echo "<script>alert('This card was not approved, Thanks.');</script>";
```

also you can con-cat PHP value in echo

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<script>alert("Region already added");</script>';
```

try this

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer